# STL container insert element

Tags: c++, stl

I was looking into `std::set` code. I see `insert` signature as `_Pairib insert(const value_type& _Val)`. Why is the input parameter passed by reference? I know that standardcContainers copy their elements into memory of the container. Does anybody know how this is achieved?  Where do allocators enter the picture? Any small code/pseudocode which explains how the elements are stored/inserted would be appreciated. I am interested in understanding how the copy is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocator is a template parameter. Look at the definition [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/):

```
template < class Key, class Compare = less<Key>,
           class Allocator = allocator<Key> > class set;
```

If you don't specify allocator of your own, it will take the default allocator (which would probably be just a `new`).

You can use STL containors on classes with public copy constructors, destructors and assignment operators. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fe2x6kt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Elements inserted into an STL container can be of any object type that
>   supplies a public copy constructor, a public destructor, and a public
>   assignment operator. The destructor may not throw an exception.
>   Furthermore, associative containers such as set and map must have a
>   public comparison operator defined, which is operator< by default.
>   Some operations on containers might also require a public default
>   constructor and a public equivalence operator.

So basically the copy is done by using the above public member functions that you implement in your classes.

Comment: so does STL call copy constructor of the user defined type and create objects into the area which is created by allocators ?

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how I can do this in C++, I mean Do i need to use placement new to achieve this.

Comment: You can overload the `new` operator, and make it do whatever you want. Placement `new` is another option, which is useful if the actual class cannot be changed. With regards to the STL containers - you can implement your own `allocator` class for your type, and pass it as the last parameter to the template. It means that you have to explicitly specify all the previous parameters (for example the comparison class, `std::less<T>`, for `std::set`).

Comment: @littleadv I believe that your last comment is off. The `new` operator is an *allocator*, and should only return a block of *uninitialized* memory. It is in no way an alternative to *placement-new*.

Comment: @David, I believe the OP's intention was to control the allocation, which is exactly the reason the allocators and the placement new's exist. Overriding the new operator is inline with the same logic - controlling the allocation. I'm not sure I understand what is it that you're objecting to.

Comment: @littleadv: *You can overload the new operator [...] placement new is another option*. They are *not* alternatives, they are solutions to completely different problems.

Comment: @David, I guess it depends on the problem. Some may be solved by both the solutions. Regardless, this discussion seems to be irrelevant to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the input parameter is passed as a reference.

If it would be taken by value, then two copies will be needed: one for the function argument, and another one for the container node.

> Where does allocators comes here in picture.

The container requests the allocator to allocate and initialize a private node type that usually contains the element type as well as other information such as pointers to other nodes.

> I am interested in understanding how the copy is done.

The private node type would hold a copy of the argument passed to `insert`.