# STL Container insert element and memory perspective

Tags: c++, stl, insert, implementation, containers

This question is extension of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871691/stl-container-insert-element) I want to understand how the elements are inserted into the `STL Container`.

Suppose I have `A object;`, which I want to insert into any of the `STL Container`, I understand that there is concept of `allocators` which handles the memory. But I fail to understand that how the actual object is copied into `STL memory`. So my `object` is stored on the `stack` when I call `Container.insert` how does STL create copy of this object and stored this objects into its memory.

Any equivalent `C++` code would be helpful which simulates the same.

Comment: @ Marcelo Cantos, I understand it uses copy constructor. But take a case of std::map, now forget about comparison logic , what really happens when a new node is actually added to tree.

Comment: I am not too sure as of what you are actually asking... Are you concerned on how the object is allocated or what the algorithm to place the node in the container is? The allocator will be used to obtain memory for a new `node`, and a constructor of `node` will be called with *placement-new*, that constructor will initialize its own data structures and *copy-construct* its `T` data member. If you are concerned about the implementation of a RB-Tree (or any other balanced binary search tree, I suggest that you google or check wikipedia)

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas  : I am interested in know how STL allocates memory for each element, Actually I am trying to figure out usage of allocator in for STL classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is not that complicated. Basically the container will obtain memory from the allocator and then perform copy-construction (with *placement-new* over that memory). The easier container to see is `vector`:

```
void push_back( T const & value ) {
   ensure_enough_capacity();
   new (end_ptr++) T( value );
}
```

Where `ensure_enough_capacity()` determines whether the vector has to grow and does it, that is, it will end up calling the allocator if `size()==capacity()` when `push_back` is called.

The next level of complexity is a `list`, where each node is allocated on its own, and there is some extra information that the library has to manage. In that case the code would look similar to:

```
void push_back( T const& value ) {
    node* n = allocator::allocate( sizeof(node) );
    new (n) node( value, x, y );
}
```

Where `x` and `y` are the appropriate pointers to initialize the node's `next` and `last` pointers (usually would be a pointer to the last node for `last` and a pointer to a sentry node --invalid beyond the end-- for `next`), and assuming that this particular constructor will *copy-construct* the `value` and then fix all referred pointers.

Ordered associative containers have the extra level of complexity of managing the balanced tree, but the approach is the same: allocate a block big enough to hold the value and the extra information, and then use *placement-new* to build the *node*. The rest are details of the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The object is copied using the appropriate copy constructor (or, maybe, the move constructor in C++11). Assume that you have pre-allocated an array of N `Foo` objects and have `length` objects already in it, the code in `std::vector` might look like:

```
void std::vector<Foo>::push_back( const Foo& n ) { 
    new( my_memory+length ) Foo(n);
    ++length;
}
```

The brackets after the new indicate "placement new", that is, calling new on pre-allocated storage.

Comment: :Thanks , but how this will work with associative containers, I know it is internally implemented as RB-Tree, but now in this case node memory will not be pre-allocated.

Comment: @Avinash: Then the node just uses the copy constructor of Foo.

Answer (score 0):

The most of the insert functions are prototyped as

```
void insert(const A& a);
```

Taking a `cost&` is -essentially- a way to pass a value without copy it in to the formal parameter.

Container -depending on how they work- have an internal structure that contains `A`s.
For example, a list has a

```
struct node
{
   A val;
   node* next;
   node* prev;

   node(const A& a) :val(a), next(), perv()
   { }  
};
```

Insert, at that point does noting more than

```
void insert(const A& a)
{
   node* n = new(allocator.allocate()) node(a);
   /*set next and prev accordingly to list functionality*/
}
```

The reference is passed through the node constructor and given to the initializer for the node's embedded A, that's its own copy constructor.

Note that allocator.allocate() atually has to allocate space for node, not just A. For that reason the allocator instance inside the list will be of type `typename Allocator::rebind<node>::other`, where `Allocator` is the second template parameter of `list`, that defaults to `std::allocator<A>`.

Answer (score 0):

what really happens in terms of memory allocation is this: _it uses the allocator passed in as the `allocator` template parameter.

```
 map<int , long , less<int> , myAllocator<pair<int, long> > > myMap;
```

whatever you make `myAllocator` do it's allocations from (if any) will be used. This technically means that you could preallocate all the pairs (perhaps from a vector). It also implicates that placement new is being used, just like in the vector case, only that, instead of a single contiguous allocation, your allocation will be called many times for small allocations.

This only leads to the situation where the container cannot *guarantee* that storage is contiguous (like in the vector case), however, it *miht* still happen to be contiguous due to the implementation of your allocator

Writing allocators is an advanced topic and it has been addressed in

- [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315) (A.Alexandrescu)
- [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html)
- See also [EASTL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) (which is designed for (embedded) game programming; In such environments, a heap is often 'non-existant' or prohibited; Moreover, performance is of the utmost importance in this area. EASTL doesn't come with a default allocator.)
  <sub>https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL</sub>